# selenium simple example- error message: can not kill the process

Tags: java, selenium, kill

I am very new in using selenium java. I went through with the online tutorial and ran a simple program to test if a page is successfully open or not.

I am not sure why these error message happened. Since I copied & pasted code from the online tutorial.

Please help!,I don't understand what goes wrong..

----The program----

```
package seleniumPrograms;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Gecko_Driver {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\bm-toshiba5\\Softwares\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");
 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

----The Error Messages ----

> 1477634165078 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:15694 Oct 28,
> 2016 4:56:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
> createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's
> Law holds true on the remote end
> 1477634165633 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path
> C:\Users\BM-TOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.lCCcXFkfXvty
> 1477634165646 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
> 1477634166149 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on
> localhost:53137 1477634167869 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53137
> 1477634170473 Marionette  INFO    startBrowser
> 2e5153b8-f5ad-4d7b-b974-d8ae27ba7b71 Oct 28, 2016 4:56:10 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
> Detected dialect: W3C [Child 9388] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 513 [Child 9388] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
> line 2052
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0xFA0005,name=PTexture::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0xFA0005,name=PTexture::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0xFA0005,name=PTexture::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0xFA0005,name=PTexture::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x400003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error:
>
> cannot send/recv

.....

Oct 28, 2016 4:56:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process with PID 5288

Answer (score 5):

You are using drive.quit() instead of driver.close().  quit closes the driver and window.  This is why you get the child error because the driver is no longer available.  close(), will close the window but keep the driver alive.  I would only use quit at the very end of your program (like a cleanup routine).  I ran your code (modified below) on my machine and did not have any errors.  Also, you should put this around a try/catch so that you can see what is going on. I found with selenium that the try/catch sometimes shows errors that your console does not show.  I had something similar with an earlier project and the try catch assisted with debugging.

```
package com.kurt.stackoverflow.selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Gecko_Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    try
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\tmp\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       driver.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Caught message " + e.getMessage());
       driver.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi sunpack, Thank you for your answer, I have tried your method, and there are two things that I have not got it, so I want to ask you again.                           1. driver.close(); in catch has an error says driver not define.                                      2. I have use driver.close(), however, it did not close the browser as I expect, how should I do that if i want to the page is closed after 5 seconds? Thank you so  much!

Comment: drive.close() does not close the browser just for firefox driver, when I use chrome, It is fine, not sure what could be wrong?

Comment: driver.close() is the preferred method and working all these years later!